# sphinx-quickstart ImportError no module named sphinx.quickstart

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am trying to run python sphinx on a CentOS-7 VM, using a virtual python 3.6.1 environment.

Steps:
Create python3 virtual environment

```
$ pyvenv myapp
$ source myapp/bin/activate
```

Install required packages for myproj

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Install sphinx

```
$ pip install sphinx sphinx-autobuild
```

Try and run the quickstart:

```
$ sphinx-quickstart
File "/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 7 in <module>
  from sphinx.quickstart import main
ImportError: No module named sphinx.quickstart
```

pip freeze indicates that I am running the following versions:

```
Sphinx==1.6.3
sphinx-autobuild==0.7.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I am new to python and pyvenv, and apparently it was finding a "universally" installed version of sphinx outside of the virtual environment, and that was preempting the version that was installed inside the virtualenv. I solved the problem by specifying the full path:

```
/full-path-to-myapp/myapp/bin/sphinx-quickstart
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyvenv` has been deprecated. See [note in the Python library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> Note: The `pyvenv` script has been deprecated as of Python 3.6 in favor of using `python3 -m venv` to help prevent any potential confusion as to which Python interpreter a virtual environment will be based on.

Instead first make sure you have not already activated a virtual environment.  Then issue the command:

```
python3 -m venv myapp
```

The rest of your steps look OK.